# How to validate a json to make sure each json object is valid?

Tags: linux, bash, python, json, jq

I have a `json` as shown below where I have multiple json objects inside `rootLevel`. I need to validate my json to make sure each json object should follow this below rules:

- Value in `clientId`, `procId` and `machineName` in each json object should be unique. If they are not unique then I want to fail it by printing what is not unique.
- Required fields are: `clientId`, `some_key6`, `some_key7`, `some_key8`, `some_key9`, `some_key10` and `machineName`. If they are not present in any json object then I want to fail it as well.

Below is my json. As of now it only has one json object in `rootLevel` array but in general it has a lot in similar fashion.

```
{
    "rootLevel": [
        {
            "clientId": 1234,
            "processId": 1,
            "clientName": "Hello",
            "some_key1": 4,
            "some_key2": 9,
            "some_key3": "rcb.com",
            "some_key4": 7,
            "some_key5": 301,
            "some_key6": 78,
            "some_key7": 2,
            "some_key8": 1,
            "some_key9": "USD",
            "some_key10": "en-US",
            "some_key11": 45,
            "some_key12": {
                "SportsId": [
                    "NBA"
                ],
                "Team": [
                    "RCB"
                ]
            },
            "procId": [
                1234
            ],
            "machineName": [
                "shop.hello.com"
            ]
        }
}
```

Can we do these validations on each json object using shell script or is there anything else suited for this? I have named few keys as `some_key#` just to make it easier to understand but in general they have different names.

Comment: Kind of a tall order.  The gold standard for processing json data is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), however I think [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) is more intuitive/user friendly.  Either tool should be able to help you write a validation script that meets your needs.

Comment: I suggest you to update your question with a minified *valid* json file. One table, 3 objects, 4 lines each, no scrollbars.

Comment: I updated the question just now.

Comment: You may want to look into using/writing a JSON schema and using a schema validator. How to do that is (I believe) too big a topic for an answer here. See e.g. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/validating-data-with-json-schema-part-1--cms-25343

Comment: @Kusalananda. I may be wrong but uniqueness in property values, other than in simple array elements, is currently not supported by any JSON schema that I am aware of.

Comment: @fpmurphy Ah, that may well be correct. A separate check for that bit would probably need to be added. Although it feels like that ought to be the task for whatever it is that is writing the JSON document.

Comment: yeah maybe it can be done using some validation script?

Comment: It could be possible that some json object might not have some fields but some json object can have those fields. When you say order what does that mean? you mean all fields will they appear in same order in each json object? if yes then no they can be in difference places as well

Comment: It is unclear what "unique" means. Should the mentioned fields be unique within an object or between all objects in the `rootLevel` array? What does that mean for the `machineName` array? Is a `machineName` array with two or more entries "the same" as another `machineName` array with the same entries in another order? Or should the array itself only contain unique strings? If `procId` and `processId` are not present (you mention that `machineName` is required, but say nothing about these other two fields), then what does it mean that they are missing in terms of uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

### Test if values are unique

If I want to do a *fast* check for if all objects in the array have unique `clientId`, I would use `jq` only to print this value and check in the shell.

```bash
< file.json jq '.rootLevel[].clientId' | awk '
    seen[$0]++ {print "FAILURE"; f=1; exit}
    END {if (!f) print "SUCCESS"}'
```

You could also do it with `jq` combining `length`, `unique`, `unique_by` or other functions, `man jq` for more.

### Print only duplicates

If you want to print all objects having duplicated `.clientId`, you could do this:

```bash
jq '.rootLevel | group_by(.clientId) | map(select(length>1))' file.json
```

`group_by` will create separate arrays per `clientId`, and we select only them with more than one element, that means those having duplicated `clientId`. Or you could add the length function to count them (another way to test if values are unique):

```bash
jq '.rootLevel | group_by(.clientId) | map(select(length>1)) | length' file.json
```

### Test if field exists for all objects

If I want to check that all objects of this json array have a `.processId` field, I would do this:

```bash
jq '.rootLevel[] | .processId?' file.json | grep -m1 null
```

and test the exit status of grep. That means this:

```bash
if jq '.rootLevel[] | .processId?' file.json | grep -qm1 null; then
    echo "FAILURE"
else
    echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

---

Combining the above directions, you can do all that you mention into your question.

If you have a lot of work to do with similar stuff, consider using a
"JSON Database" (or "Document Database" or "Nosql Database").

Comment: Sorry I was out for a while. Is there any way to combine all these in one shell script? I am kinda new so having issues in converting that.

Comment: Yes, and basic shell scripting skills are required. If you have a spesific question about how to do that, you can post new questions or find your answers on existing posts.